# Break strings into codes

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of the format

```
array(
      [0]=>x_4556v_7889;
      [1]=>y_9908;
      [2]=>f_5643u_7865;
   )
```

I need to get output as

```
   array(
          [0]=> ([0] =>4556;
                 [1] =>7889;
                )
          [1]=>( [0]=>9908;)
          [2] =>([0] =>5643;
                 [1]=>7865;
                )

     )
```

how to use strpos and find out the occurance of "_"(underscore) in string and get the next four characters in for loop.
Am getting only the first four digit code the next four digit are not getting.Kindly provide some logic.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. **You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you.** Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to find all the numbers. In that case, consider trying this:

```
$output = array_map(function($item) {
    preg_match_all("/\d+/",$item,$m);
    return $m[0];
},$input);
```

Should work just fine :)

Comment: any other idea without using preg_match_all.Anyways thanks for the suggest

Comment: @SSS, Why not `preg_match_all()` ? It's the right way to do. Niet +1

Answer (score 0):

#### This is a regex free solution though..

```
$arr = array(
    0=>'x_4556v_7889;',
    1=>'y_9908;',
    2=>'f_5643u_7865;'
   );

$lettersarr = range('a','z');
array_unshift($lettersarr,'_');
array_unshift($lettersarr,';');

$new_arr=array_map(function ($v) use($lettersarr) {
    return explode('@',wordwrap(str_replace($lettersarr,'',$v), 4, "@", true)); },$arr);
print_r($new_arr);
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/148250)</kbd>